# How can I use a registered controller in my angular directive?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a controller registered like this:

```
myModule.controller('MyController', function ($scope, ...some dependencies...)
{
    ....
```

Using `ng-controller="MyController"` in the HTML it all works fine, but now I want to use this controller as my directive's controller. Some thing like this:

```
otherModule.directive('myDirective', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        replace: true,
        controller: ??????????,
        scope: {
            foo: '=',
            blah: '=',
        },
        template: '....'
    }
});
```

I tired just putting `MyController` but it errors out saying "MyController is not defined". I'm sure if I just put `MyController` in the global namespace, it would work fine, but I don't want anything in the global namespace. If it makes a difference, `myModule` is defined as a dependency for `otherModule`. How can I get a reference to this controller for my directive to use?

As suggested, I tried `$controller('MyController')`, but now I am getting the following error:

```
Error: Unknown provider: $scopeProvider <- $scope <- myDirectiveDirective
at Error (<anonymous>)
at http://localhost/resources/angular.js?_=1360613988651:2627:15
at Object.getService [as get] (http://localhost/resources/angular.js?_=1360613988651:2755:39)
at http://localhost/resources/angular.js?_=1360613988651:2632:45
at getService (http://localhost/resources/angular.js?_=1360613988651:2755:39)
at invoke (http://localhost/resources/angular.js?_=1360613988651:2773:13)
at Object.instantiate (http://localhost/resources/angular.js?_=1360613988651:2805:23)
at http://localhost/resources/angular.js?_=1360613988651:4621:24
at otherModule.directive.restrict (http://localhost/resources/app.js?_=1360613988824:862:15)
at Object.invoke (http://localhost/resources/angular.js?_=1360613988651:2786:25)
```

I'm not sure what to make of this error. Is there more needed to make this work?

Comment: It is a bit odd to have a directive's controller constructor function be defined outside the directive.  If for no other reason, the injectable arguments are different for directive controller constructor functions vs the ng-controller kind of controller constructor functions.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

It appears that you can just use:

```
controller: 'MyController'
```

IF the controller is in the same module as the directive or a higher level module composed of the module with the directive in it.

When I tried it with two different modules composed into an app module (one for the controller and one for the directive), that did not work.

Comment: +1 this answer is the best... but for anyone else that finds this and needs to access a controller in another module, I've added another answer.

Comment: This way creates a new instance of `MyController`... is there any way to access the existing one?

Comment: No you can't. If you want to share a controller, then nest the directives in a div ng-controller and don't use isolated scope.

Answer (score 10):

The answer you've already accepted works, and in *almost all cases should be chosen*...

**For sake of completeness: Here is how you can use a controller from another module**

(PS: Don't do this. lol :P)

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['myDirectives']);

app.controller('AppCtrl1', function($scope) {
    $scope.foo = 'bar';
});


var directives = angular.module('myDirectives', []);

directives.directive('test', function($controller) {
   return {
       template: '<h1>{{foo}}</h1>',
       link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
          var controller = $controller('AppCtrl1', { $scope: scope });

          console.log($scope.foo); //bar
       }
   };
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, and you're right, we shouldn't do this.

Comment: Why not? Looks pretty clean to me.

Comment: @nikkwong Well, FWIW, beauty is in the eye of the beholder... But injecting a dependencyA ($controller) to get a dependencyB (AppCtrl1) by hardcoding dependencyB's dependencies ($scope) into a function call is not at all what I'd call "clean".