# How to move standalone controller into a directive?

Tags: angularjs

I had a working angular app, but I want to restructure it a bit. I had a pile of directives that weren't really doing anything, and although the entire app was supposed to be encapsulated by a single directive, I still had my two main controller declarations outside that directive.

I merged those two controllers, because although they take care of different concerns (one handles functional data, the other navigation state), they are both necessary for the entire app.

Secondly, I wanted to get rid of the loose declaration and go from:

```
<div ng-app="myApp" class="myApp" ng-cloak ng-controller="myController">
    <myAppdirective ng-controller="myNavigationController"></myAppdirective>
</div>
```

to:

```
angular.module('myApp').
    directive('myAppDirective', ['myController', function(myController) { {

        return {
            restrict: 'AE',
            replace: true,
            scope: true,
            controller: myController,
            template:   '<div>' +
                            '<ng-include src="\'partials/navigation.html\'">' +
                            '<ng-view></ng-view>' +
                        '</div>'
        };
}]);
```

Mysteriously, this doesn't work. Shouldn't this work?

I get this error: https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/unpr?p0=myControllerProvider%20%3C-%20myController%20%3C-%20myAppDirective

I tried using ngController inside the template, but that gave me `TypeError: Cannot read property 'insertBefore' of null` somewhere deep in angular code.

I'm at a loss. I'm probably doing somthing fundamentally wrong. But what?

**Solution:** I reverted the merging of my two controllers. This restores the separation of concerns I originally had, and it fixes that mysterious TypeError.

My directive now looks like this:

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    /*global angular */
    angular.module('myApp').
    directive('myAppDirective', function() {

        return {
            restrict: 'AE',
            replace: true,
            scope: true,
            controller: 'myController',
            template:   '<div ng-controller="myNavigationController">' +
                            '<ng-include src="\'partials/navigation.html\'"></ng-include>' +
                            '<ng-view></ng-view>' +
                        '</div>'
        };
    });
})();
```

This seems to work fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can inject controller instances. That's probably where the error is coming from (based on that error, it looks like you renamed your actual controller name when posting the question). You should just need to use a string for the controller property.

```
angular.module('myApp').
    directive('myAppDirective', [function() { {

        return {
            restrict: 'AE',
            replace: true,
            scope: true,
            controller: 'myController',
            template:   '<div>' +
                            '<ng-include src="\'partials/navigation.html\'">' +
                            '<ng-view></ng-view>' +
                        '</div>'
        };
}]);
```

See [How can I use a registered controller in my angular directive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14819776/how-can-i-use-a-registered-controller-in-my-angular-directive)

Comment: Looks promising, but doesn't quite work for me yet. I still get the `TypeError: Cannot read property 'insertBefore' of null` error. I wonder if that could be caused by my merging the two controllers (something I'm still not entirely happy with, because of separation of concerns).

Comment: Reverting the merger of those two controllers solved the TypeError. Your `controller: 'myController',` works. I've added the second controller in the template, and that works too. Maybe not the prettiest way to combine two controllers, but at least I keep the code separate again, have everything encapsulated in directives, and don't need several useless directives anymore, which is exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

By default, the `scope` property of every directive is set to `false` unless other specified. You are setting your `scope` to true, then applying the same controller that the directive is located in.

Simply put, remove `scope: true`, and `controller: myController` - your directive will inherit the `scope` from the parent controller and all will be well.