# Jasmine angular directive being compiled as an object

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine, directive, angular-mock

I am unit testing an Angular directive, and this test has worked in the past with Angular 1.4.9.  I recently upgraded to 1.5.0, so I am thinking this problem/(unexpected result) may be due to `angular-mocks`.

```
describe('The buttonToggle directive', function() {
  var $compile,
    btElement = '<button-toggle></button-toggle>',
    compiledElement,
    btElementPath = 'button-toggle.html',
    $scope;

  beforeEach(inject(function(_$compile_, $templateCache, $rootScope) {
    $compile = _$compile_;
    $scope = $rootScope.$new();
    var template = $templateCache.get(btElementPath);
    $templateCache.put(btElementPath, template);
    var element = angular.element(btElement);
    compiledElement = $compile(element)($scope);
    console.log(compiledElement);
    $scope.$digest();
    console.log(compiledElement);
  }));

  it('should compile', function() {
    expect(compiledElement.html()).toContain('btn');
  });
});
```

`compiledElement` is just being put into an object.  Here is the return value from `console.log`:

```
{0: <button-toggle class="ng-scope"></button-toggle>, length: 1}
```

I don't understand why this is happening.  It should be compiled into the `button-toggle.html` contents.

**EDIT:** Forgot to inject the buttonToggle module in a beforeEach.  Do I also need to main application module injected?  If I insert it then I get an `undefined is not an object (evaluation compiledElement.html)`.

The module injections:

```
beforeEach(module('ocapp.buttonToggle'));
beforeEach(module('ocapp'));
```

**EDIT 2:** I no longer think it's an `angular-mocks` version issue. My directive is depending upon a controller defined in a separate file, and it's not being resolved.

**button-toggle.directive.js**

```
(function() {
  'use strict';

  angular
    .module('ocapp.buttonToggle')
    .directive('buttonToggle', buttonToggle);

  function buttonToggle(ButtonToggleController) {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      templateUrl: 'app/button-toggle/button-toggle.html',
      replace: true,
      scope: {
        on: '='
      },
      controller: ButtonToggleController
    };
  }
})();
```

`button-toggle.html` is in the same directory as all of the other files used here, perhaps I don't need the extended path in teh `templateUrl` property?

**EDIT 3:** I've worked through all of the other problems and am back to square one.

**button-toggle.directive.spec.js**

```
describe('The buttonToggle directive', function() {
  var $compile,
    btElement = '<button-toggle></button-toggle>',
    compiledElement,
    btElementPath = 'app/button-toggle/button-toggle.html',
    $scope,
    $httpBackend;

  beforeEach(module('ocapp.buttonToggle'));
  //beforeEach(module('ocapp'));

  beforeEach(inject(function(_$compile_, $templateCache, $rootScope, $injector) {
    $compile = _$compile_;
    $scope = $rootScope.$new();
    $httpBackend = $injector.get('$httpBackend');
    $httpBackend.whenGET(btElementPath).respond(200, '');
    var template = $templateCache.get(btElementPath);
    $templateCache.put(btElementPath, template);
    var element = angular.element(btElement);
    compiledElement = $compile(element)($scope);
    console.log(compiledElement);
    $scope.$digest();
  }));

  it('should compile', function() {
    expect(compiledElement.html()).toContain('btn');
  });
});
```

See [this question and accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14819776/how-can-i-use-a-registered-controller-in-my-angular-directive) for how to define an external controller from the same module in a directive.

**button-toggle.directive.js**

```
(function() {
  'use strict';

  angular
    .module('ocapp.buttonToggle')
    .directive('buttonToggle', buttonToggle);

  function buttonToggle() {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      templateUrl: 'app/button-toggle/button-toggle.html',
      replace: true,
      scope: {
        on: '='
      },
      controller: 'ButtonToggleController'
    };
  }
})();
```

Comment: be sure that you also using angular-mocks 1.5

Comment: Yessir, I am.  Forgot to inject the modules, but now I am getting a different error.

Answer (score 1):

It turned out to not be an Angular version issue, but rather a missing dependency.

1. Install `karma-ng-html2js-preprocessor` with npm.
2. Edit `karma.conf.js`.
3. Change directive's `templateUrl` to `'button-toggle.html'`.
4. Test should look like below.

**karma.conf.js** additions

```
preprocessors: {
   '**/*.html': ['ng-html2js']
},

ngHtml2JsPreprocessor: {
   stripPrefix: 'app/button-toggle/'
   moduleName: 'templates'
},
```

**button-toggle.directive.spec.js**

```
describe('The buttonToggle directive', function() {

  var $compile,
    btElement = '<button-toggle></button-toggle>',
    compiledElement,
    btElementPath = 'app/button-toggle/button-toggle.html',
    $scope,
    element;

  beforeEach(module('ocapp.buttonToggle'));
  beforeEach(module('templates'));

  beforeEach(inject(function(_$compile_, $templateCache, $rootScope) {
    $compile = _$compile_;
    $scope = $rootScope;
    var template = $templateCache.get(btElementPath);
    $templateCache.put(btElementPath, template);
    element = angular.element(btElement);
    compiledElement = $compile(element)($scope);
    $scope.$digest();
  }));

  it('should compile', function() {
    expect(compiledElement.html()).toContain('btn');
  });
});
```